# IPhone Application Size

Tags: iphone

I have developed an IPhone application and i would like to know what will be the size of the application when installed in iphone. I am using xcode 3.

Can anyone please help me to find the size of the application?

Comment: Any reason you can't just compile it and see how big the binary bundle is?

Comment: I have posted the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427254/how-to-obtain-the-size-of-a-application-directory-in-iphone

Answer (score 4):

For anyone using Xcode 4+, you can just go to Product->Archive and then click on Share to create an ipa file. Then just save this ipa file and find out the file size in the Finder.

These seems to be the most reliable way of checking the true size of the ipa file.

Answer (score 2):

Build the application, and then navigate to the directory where your builds are put when complete.

You can then use the Finder's "Get Info..." to see the size of the application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You mean the build folder completely? Inside the build folder, i have MyApplication.build folder and debug-MyApplication folder.

Comment: I think iPhone apps are distributed as compressed ipa files, so it's possible that user perceived size is actually smaller than this.

Comment: That is a good point. But without knowing what compression is used, or being able to create your own .ipa archive, this is probably the closest you can get.

Comment: Also remember that after installing to the iphone the .ipa is uncompressed - so it would still consume the same amount of space as the uncompressed .app.

Comment: The debug-MyApplication folder will contain your built application. If you change the build configuration, it will reflect in the build directory - ie. release-MyApplication or Distribution-MyApplication.

Comment: Just for the records: IPAs are ZIP compressed

Comment: How big it is after decompression is hardly relevant imo. Knowing how big it will be to download [when it's compressed] is, considering that only apps smaller than 10 MB can be downloaded using 3G. WiFi is required for bigger ones.

Thanks, Till, for the compression info.

Answer (score 2):

iPhone apps seem to be distributed as .ipa files, which are just thinly disguised zip files,
so if you right click your app and compress it in the finder, you should 
have a pretty good idea
 of how big it will be on the iPhone.

Comment: Not true, since it'll be decompressed again on the phone! However, I believe it's a reasonable estimate of the size that appears on the App Store (which IIRC is what matters for the "downloadable over cellular network" check), except that the app binary will be encrypted, which increases the payload size slightly.

Comment: Whoops, comprehension fail - I assumed this was "how big over the network". I guess the upvoters did too.

Answer (score 1):

Project > archive;

Window > organizer > archives (tab up top between projects and documentation) > select your archive and press "estimate app store size" button.